# Does the Laplacian commutes with the indicator function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, laplacian

We define the laplacian operator $\Delta$ with the Neumann boundary conditions on the space $H^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$, and let $\chi_\omega$ denotes the indicator function on a subdomain $\omega$ of $\Omega$.

Do we have
$$\chi_\omega\Delta=\Delta\chi_\omega?$$

Comment: Are you asking if the spectral projections $E$ of $\Delta$ commute with (the bounded operator) $\chi_{\omega}$? This is clearly not the case; for example, assume that $\Delta$ has an eigenfunction $u$ and check how $\chi_{\omega}E$ and $E\chi_{\omega}$ act on $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails even in the case of the one dimensional case on an interval since the rhs picks up $\delta$ functions at the endpoints due to the jump singularities there and these are abseent in the lhs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question. If you intend the question as

$$
\chi_\omega\Delta u \overset{?}{=} \Delta(\chi_\omega u)
$$
for $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, then I would say no, since $\chi_\omega u\notin H^2$ in general.